# Perform push segue after an unwind segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unwind-segue

I am working on a camera app where the camera views are shown modally. After I am done with cropping. I perform an unwind segue to the `MainPageViewController`. (Please see the screenshot)

[image: storyboard]

My unwind function inside `MainPageViewController` is as follows;

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Categories", sender: self)
}
```

where "categories" is the push segue identifier from `MainPageViewController` to `CategoriesTableViewController`.

The program enters the `unwindToMainMenu` function but it does not perform the push segue. Any idea how to fix this?

Note: I found the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503886/performing-programmatic-segue-after-unwind) but the answer suggests to change the storyboard structure.

Comment: wether this unwinding properly to the `MainPageViewController `?

Comment: I can unwind properly, But I want to perform push segue immediately after I unwind to `MainPageViewController`

Comment: You can catch the end of the segue. See that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310396/how-to-execute-some-code-after-a-segue-is-done

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A bit late to the party but I found a way to do this without using state flags

Note: this only works with iOS 9+, as only custom segues support class names prior to iOS9 and you cannot declare an exit segue as a custom segue in storyboards

### 1. Subclass UIStoryboardSegue with UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion

```
class UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion: UIStoryboardSegue {
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    override func perform() {
        super.perform()
        if let completion = completion {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Set UIStoryBoardSegueWithCompletion as the class for your exit segue

note: the action for this segue should be `unwindToMainMenu` to match the original question

[image: Select exit segue from storyboard]
[image: Add custom class]

### 3. Update your unwind @IBAction to execute the code in the completion handler

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let segue = segue as? UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion {
        segue.completion = { 
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Categories", sender: self) 
        }
    }
}
```

Your code will now execute after the exit segue completes its transition

Comment: I could only get this to work reliably by wrapping the completion inside a transition coordinator:

    `destinationViewController.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: { _ in
    completion()
 })`

Comment: @Bringo that's interesting... If you're setting the transition coordinator then perhaps you can just directly set the completion block of the transition coordinator from the unwind action, instead of having to go through a custom segue

Comment: okay you can't since there's no transition active during the unwind segue call, therefore the transition coordinator is nil (ie the transition happens after the unwind segue call returns)

Comment: This is causing memory leaks in my app! :(

Comment: you probably want to put weak self in the segue completion. Let me know if that fixes your memory leak and I can update the answer @TomCalmon

Comment: No, that didn't fix the problem. I ended up setting some flags and execute code in `viewDidDisappear(animated:)`.

Answer (score 12):

I want to provide my own solution to this problem for now. Any further answers are always welcome.

I put a boolean variable and viewDidAppear function to `MainPageViewController`.

```
var fromCamera = false

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if fromCamera {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("categorySelection", sender: self)
        self.fromCamera = false
    }
}
```

I set `fromCamera` to `true` before I perform unwind segue from `CropViewController`. By that way, I perform segue to category screen only if an unwind segue from crop view is performed.

Comment: The more reliable solution. But unfortunately I have to resort to the hackish solutions when unwinding from a modally presented view as `viewDidAppear` is not called in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Taking forward [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602422/1685709) (I only had Objective-C code)

Subclass `UIStoryBoardSegue`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyStoryboardSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

/**
 This block is called after completion of animations scheduled by @p self.
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completion)();

@end
```

And call this completion block after completion of animations.

```
@implementation MyStoryboardSegue

- (void)perform {
  [super perform];
  if (self.completion != nil) {
    [self.destinationViewController.transitionCoordinator
     animateAlongsideTransition:nil
     completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
       if (![context isCancelled]) {
         self.completion();
       }
     }];
  }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking forward the previous two answers, there is a bit more detail about the objective c version here (I too only had Objective-C code)

1. Subclass UIStoryboardSegue with UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion

   class UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion: UIStoryboardSegue {
       var completion: (() -> Void)?

   ```
   override func perform() {
       super.perform()
       if let completion = completion {
           completion()
       }
   }
   ```

   }

UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyStoryboardSegue : UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^completion)();

@end
```

UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion.m

```
#import "UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion.h"

@implementation UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion

- (void)perform {
  [super perform];
  if (self.completion != nil) {
    [self.destinationViewController.transitionCoordinator
     animateAlongsideTransition:nil
     completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
       if (![context isCancelled]) {
         self.completion();
       }
     }];
  }
}
@end
```

2. Set UIStoryBoardSegueWithCompletion as the class for your exit segue

note: the action for this segue should be unwindToMainMenu to match the original question
[image showing segue ui][1] 
[image showing segue ui 2][2]

Select exit segue from storyboard Add custom class

```
-(IBAction)unwindToMainMenu(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    if([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion class]]){
        UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion *segtemp = segue;// local prevents warning
        segtemp.completion = ^{
            NSLog(@"segue completion");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Categories" sender:self];
        };
    }
}
```

Your code will now execute after the exit segue completes its transition

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the performSegue is not firing because the unwind segue has not yet finished.  The only thing I can think of at the moment, is to delay calling the performSegue using `dispatch_after`.  This seems very "hacky" to me though.

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Categories", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I also find a way which might also be "hacky"; I set a boolean variable to true inside the unwind function and inside the viewDidAppear function, I call the performForSegue function if that boolean is true. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: I think that's a good solution.  `dispatch_after`, due to the variable wait time, may have issues.  Using the boolean and viewDidAppear ensures the perfromSegue will execute when the view is ready.

Answer (score 3):

The exit segue IBAction method happens before the actual unwind segue is finished. I had the same issue and resolved it this way (if you don't mind my paraphrasing of your code). It avoids the extra time and animations from relying on ViewDidAppear.

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
   let categoriesTable = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoryTableViewController")
   self.navigationController?.viewControllers.append(categoriesTable)
   self.navigationController?.showViewController(categoriesTable, sender: self)
}
```

Hope this is helpful for anyone else who runs into this and just wants an instantaneous transition!

Answer (score 3):

Updated @moride's answer for **Swift 5**. The transition coordinator is now optional, so we run completion immediately if this is the case.

```
class UIStoryboardSegueWithCompletion: UIStoryboardSegue {
    var completion: (() -> Void)?

    override func perform() {
        super.perform()

        guard let completion = completion else { return }
        guard let coordinator = destination.transitionCoordinator else {
            completion()
            return
        }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { context in
            guard !context.isCancelled else { return }
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```